# How to: Header with auto width and a background line

Tags: css

First of all, sorry for the title, I didn´t even know how to explain that so I just uploaded this picture:

[those are the headers](http://postimg.org/image/i2mfmkenz/)

What I need is this, I need a header with width auto (depending on the text) and a blue line taking the rest of the width. I did it before this way:

```
<div class="widgettitlewrapper"><h3 class="widgettitle">HEADER2</h3></div>
```

```css
.widgettitlewrapper {
  background: url("../img/ntitle2.png") repeat-x scroll left center transparent;
}
.widgettitlewrapper h3.widgettitle {
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FAF8F8;
}
```

So I had a blue line and on top of it, the header with a BACKGROUND covering the line in that part. The problem is that now I need the header to be transparent, so I can see the line under this header.

How can I fix this? I´m trying to search on Google and here but I don´t even know what to search for...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution, apply the background to an :after pseudo-element :

```
.widgettitlewrapper {
    clear:both;
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}
.widgettitlewrapper h3.widgettitle {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FAF8F8;
    background:transparent;
     display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
}

.widgettitlewrapper:after{
    content: '.';
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-color: red;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You just need to change the background of the .widgettitlewrapper:after element.

fiddle : [http://jsfiddle.net/oadpunpa/](http://jsfiddle.net/oadpunpa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your title's `background` css with this:

```
.widgettitlewrapper h3.widgettitle {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

See **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5guvredj/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements to draw a border instead.

```
.widgettitle {
    color: blue;
    position: relative;
}

.widgettitle:after {
    content: "";
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;    
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0k33cL4v/)